# Finding Accuracy for this K-Means model

Tags: python, k-means

This program predicts the cluster to which the coordinates belong to, where it divides the given points into two clusters 0 and 1.
How do I get the accuracy of this model for the variable - prediction

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans  
#from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score  
X = np.array([[1, 2],[5, 8],[1.5, 1.8],[8, 8],[6,7],[9, 11]])  
print(X)  
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)  
kmeans.fit(X)  
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_  
labels = kmeans.labels_  
print("Centroids :\n ",centroids)  
print("Labels    : ",labels)  
colors = ["g.","r.","c.","y."]  
for i in range(len(X)):  
print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])  
plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)  
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths 
= 5, zorder = 10)  
plt.show() 
prediction=kmeans.predict ( [ [ 5,6 ] ] )   
print(prediction)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "accuracy" of this model for the variable prediction? I guess the predict method on a new point will just returns the label of the cluster whose centroid is the closest to the new point. Do you already have some known labels?

Comment: [1. 2.]       1      
        [5. 8.]       0     
        [1.5 1.8]   1     
        [8. 8.]       0     
        [6. 7.]       0           these  zeroes and ones are the labels

Comment: Are these 0 and 1 the result of the kmeans clustering ? or are they labels that you know before the program runs ? In the first case, computing an accuracy is not possible because you don't have ground truth labelling. In the second case, you can compute the accuracy as the number of labels correctly assigned divided by the number of points. `np.sum(true_labels == predictions) / len(true_labels)`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the correct values for the coordinates' labels, you can use `scikit-learn's` [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

This does seem tricky for a clustering problem though. Think about how you would determine whether a prediction is correct or not and calculate the accuracy around that.